# Mongo slow query for collection with 3m

Tags: performance, mongodb

i have some performance issue with mongo.

I have this collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "status" : String,
    "song" : ObjectId,
    "room" : ObjectId,
    "duration" : Number,
    "order" : 0,
    "addedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T14:16:21.331Z"),
    "startedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T14:16:21.393Z")
}
```

And into it I have the following indexes:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.mycollection"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "song" : 1
        },
        "name" : "song_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.mycollection",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    "2" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "user" : 1
        },
        "name" : "user_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.mycollection",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    "3" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "room" : 1
        },
        "name" : "room_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.mycollection",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    "4" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "duration" : 1
        },
        "name" : "duration_1",
        "ns" : "mydb.mycollection",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    }
}
```

The collection have more than 3m records within it.

Now, the Mongo show me this slow query info in the log (indented for readability):

```
2016-02-11T11:07:47.897+0000 [conn19] query mydb.mycollection query: {
    orderby: { startedAt: -1 },
    $query: { status: {$in: [ "ended", "skipped" ] }, room: ObjectId('myroomid') } }
    planSummary: IXSCAN {room: 1 }, IXSCAN { room: 1 } cursorid:64767933277   
    noreturn:10
    ntoskip:0
    nscanned:41663
    nscannedObjects:41663 keyUpdates:0
    numYields:4 locks(micros) r:2949888
    nreturned:10 realen:2668
    1737ms
```

As you can see the execution time is 1737ms (and sometimes even more) and i also experience with high CPU utilization.

Anyone know why? any indexes I need to add? is it too much data 3M records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Although there are index intersections those don't apply here and in general, a good **rule of thumb** is

> MongoDB uses only one index per query.

So, your query is on two fields (`status` and `room`) and orders by an additional one (`startedAt`). The query plan used clearly shows that it utilizes the index on `room` only. For all other values, it reads the documents matching the `room` part of your query, as indicated by `nscanned` and `nscannedObjects`.

In order to make full use of an index here, you need a compound index on `room`, `status` and `startedAt`. Note that order matters, so if your query looks something like this:

```
db.rooms.find({
    room: someRoomId,
    status: {$in: [ "ended", "skipped" ]
}).sort({startedAt:-1})
```

the according index should be

```
db.rooms.createIndex({room:1,status:1,startedAt:-1})
```

If your query looks like

```
db.rooms.find({
    status: {$in: [ "ended", "skipped" ],
    room: someRoomId
}).sort({startedAt:-1})
```

your index should be

```
db.rooms.createIndex({status:1,room:1,startedAt:-1})
```

With the indices set accordingly, your query should be a lot faster.

**Side note**

You use `ObjectId` with a string value in your example. This does not make sense at all. You can either use the string you used there directly (say, the room number) or use an ObjectId() as returned by `new ObjectId()` altogether. There is no need to use an ObjectId() when the cardinality of your field is high enough (as given by a room number, for example – it is unlikely that there are two rooms with the same number in the same building).

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, in your side not i assume you meant this `ObjectId('myroomid')`, i just changed that for this example, of course there was there some valid object id.

Comment: Just to understand it better, should i add an index for the 3 fields in addition to the 4 indexes i already have? if so, is Mongo will know to use this one automatically cause the query structure fit it?

Comment: I'd add that new one first and delete the old ones after you made sure everything works as expected, since – yes – mongodb figures out which index to use.

Comment: For use prefixes `db.rooms.createIndex({startedAt:-1,status:1,room:1})` isn't better ? Because in other queries you can just use startedAt prefix with this index also without status and room. [Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix)

Comment: I may still need other indexes cause in other places in the system I have different queries: e.g room id alone, room id and user id, room id and song id and so on.. so is it will be good practice to create compound indexes for each meaningful combination?

Comment: @MaDeRkAn order matters ;), so it depends on the actual queries, hence there is no general "better". And, as you will find out, single fields of an compound index can be used regardless of their position.

Comment: @ShlomiSasson There is no golden bullet when it comes to indexing. You really need to dive deep into https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/, namely https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/ and https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, small question, i read what you sent and decided I need to create specific indexes combination to the places in my system I have heavy read operations. so I moved all over my code follow it I made these indexes: http://snag.gy/OV40m.jpg - somehow it's looks inefficient and also make the data folder twice bigger.. shall I really need to do that? what do you think?

Comment: Again: there is no golden bullet. Actually, this is much dependent on your use cases and whatnot, some research and alike, being much out of scope of SO. You can contact me (see profile) for an offer: optimization takes (a lot of) time.

Answer (score 1):

`numYields:4 locks(micros) r:2949888` does not look good.
It basically says that the query was interrupted 4 times to let other operations to complete.

Comment: The `nscanned` and `nscannedObjects` look much worse. Actually, a yield does not denote an interruption, but the query yielding the lock to other operations for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Add `startedAt` descending index (-1). If you use `or` select biggest set first. If you use `and` select the smallest set first. This will help also.

So you have `room: ObjectId('myroomid')` this should be before `status: {$in: [ "ended", "skipped" ] }`.

I assume `room: ObjectId('myroomid')` count is less than `status: {$in: [ "ended", "skipped" ] }`count.